# Is there a way to build model according to other model's records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, mongoid, models

For example:

Environment:

Ruby 1.9.2

Rails 3.0.5

Mongoid

I have a Survey model and embeds many Questions in it. Now I want to define a function "publish" in surveys_controller.rb which can create model dynamically according to Survey's records (i.e., objects):

```
#surveys_controller.rb
def publish
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @questions = Survey.questions
  ... how to build a model? ...
  @questions.each do |question|
    ... and then how to add fields (named with question.title) and define type (named with question.type) ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Do you mean to instantiate an existing model 9eg the Question model) or to really create a brand new Model Object (called what?) that will create a brand new table in the database... on the fly? I'd recommend against that, btw... perhaps if you explain a bit more why you think you need to do this, we can reformulate your design and do something that will work within the existing codebase a bit more.

Comment: @Taryn is right, the way you express it seems you're confusing an object with a class, a model with a record from this model. I think what you want is to create a `Question` record associated with your `Survey` record, so i'll answer on how to do it - but if you really confuse an object with a class, you should really learn more about OOP, this is really important.

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming your models looks like this:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

you can create a question associated to a survey this way:

```
def publish
  # here, we instantiate an object by loading
  # a record from the Survey model
  @survey = Survey.find( params[:id] )
  # here, we instantiate an object of class Question,
  # associated to our object from class Survey.
  # the argument passed to the build() method 
  # depends on your form.
  @question = @survey.questions.build( params[:question] )
  # when we save our @survey, its associated @question
  # will be saved as well
  @survey.save
end
```

you may want to add `validates_associated :questions` to your `Survey` model, to make sure your questions are valid when saved.
More information is available in [Ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) and in [Rails API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated)